# Creating reusable py.text fixtures

Tags: python, pytest

I made a basic package to facilitate the use of SQLAlchemy in Pyramid applications: [pyramid_sqlalchemy](https://pyramid-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). When you write tests for an application using this package you will need some fixtures to provide a working database environment. These fixtures are completely generic and do not need to be customised for an application. At this moment these fixtures are listed in the [testing chapter of the documentation](https://pyramid-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tests.html#py-test-fixtures) and require people to copy & paste them into their code. Needless to say this is not ideal.

Is there a simple way for pyramid_sqlalchemy to expose those fixtures in a way other packages can use them directly? I tried a naive approach by creating a pyramid_sqlalchemy.fixtures module with all the fixtures and doing a `from pyramid_sqlalchemy.fixtures import *` in the `conftest.py` of the application tests, but that did not result in the fixtures being picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation about installing external plugins at http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#making-your-plugin-installable-by-others.

Basically you create a python package with a setuptools entry point:

```
# sample ./setup.py file
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="myproject",
    packages = ['myproject']

    # the following makes a plugin available to pytest
    entry_points = {
        'pytest11': [
            'name_of_plugin = myproject.pluginmodule',
            ]
    },
)
```

Where `myproject.pluginmodule` is a module containing your fixtures. Then installing that package using `pip` will make `pytest` load it at startup. For an example, see [pytest-mock](https://github.com/nicoddemus/pytest-mock/blob/master/setup.py) or any other pytest plugin.

Hope that helps,